# Runtime error on the exact same code on a different computer

Tags: java, eclipse

I am working with a relativly unknown API. (ScrumWorks Pro) I am using it to export data into a SQL database. My issue is that I have moved my eclipse project from one computer to another and it stopped working. It continues to run fine on the old computer but I am getting the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Failed to access the WSDL at: http://XXXXXXX:8080/scrumworks-api/api2/scrumworks?wsdl. It failed with: 
    Got Server returned HTTP response code: 503 for URL: http://XXXXXXXXXX:8080/scrumworks-api/api2/scrumworks?wsdl while opening stream from http://dxzbid01.zhi.com:8080/scrumworks-api/api2/scrumworks?wsdl.
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.tryWithMex(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.parseWSDL(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createServiceDelegate(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.create(Unknown Source)
    at com.danube.scrumworks.api2.ScrumWorksService.getConnection(ScrumWorksService.java:53)
    at main.connectAPI(main.java:69)
    at main.main(main.java:12)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Got Server returned HTTP response code: 503 for URL: http://XXXXXXXXX:8080/scrumworks-api/api2/scrumworks?wsdl while opening stream from http://XXXXXXXXXXXXX.com:8080/scrumworks-api/api2/scrumworks?wsdl
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.createReader(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.resolveWSDL(Unknown Source)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 503 for URL: http://XXXXXXXXXXX:8080/scrumworks-api/api2/scrumworks?wsdl
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(Unknown Source)
    ... 13 more
```

It looks like while it's running its failing to connect to the host. But it works completely fine with the exact same credentials on the other computer.

Comment: May be ports & firewalls?

Comment: You moved server or client to another PC?

Comment: No the server is unchanged, just the java project that connects to the server was moved to another computer... I'll ask around if it could be a firewall issue. I am on the same network.

Comment: additionally, I can access the server via the web browser fine on both computers

Comment: are you able to access the WSDL url from the failing computer?

Comment: Could you check at your server, does it has requests from both PCs? Also do you use any proxies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the newer computer had a newer version of Java installed which broke parts of the API.

Answer (score 1):

The magic words: `Server returned HTTP response code: 503`. The answer will be in your server logs.

From https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.5.4:

```
The server is currently unable to handle the request due to a 
temporary overloading or maintenance of the server.
```

Comment: But it gives this code every time. Even when I can access the server via other machines.

Comment: It makes no sense that you'd get a valid response when the server returns a 503. You need to look at your logs.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that url

```
http://XXXXXXXXXX:8080/scrumworks-api/api2/scrumworks?wsdl
```

is accessible, if not able to access the 8080 port, check your firewall settings in that machine (allow that 8080 port to accessible)